# Design state diagram of turing machine that multiplies a unary number by 2

Tags: automata, finite-automata, turing-machines

If the input is 1^n, the output should be in the format X^n 1^2n. For example if the input is 11, the output should be XX1111.
**Note**
A number N is represented as a unary number by repeating the digit 1 , N number of times.

Comment: might want to try https://cs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: What have you tried so far? Right now it looks like you're just trying to get us to do your homework for you.

Answer (score 0):

Our strategy will be to replace the last `1` on the input tape with `X`, write two `1`s to the right, and repeat with the next `1` to the left of all `X`s, until we run out of `1`s to the left of `X`s.

```
q    t    q'    t'    d
-----------------------
q0   #    hA    #     -        // accept the empty tape

q0   1    q1    1     right    // move to the end of input
q1   1    q1    1     right    // if the tape is not empty
q1   #    q2    #     left

q2   X    q2    X     left     // look for the last 1 remaining
q2   1    q3    X     right    // from the input and cross it out.
q2   #    hA    #     -        // accept if no more 1s

q3   X    q3    X     right    // move right until you find a
q3   1    q3    1     right    // blank cell. then, write two
q3   #    q4    1     right    // 1s to the tape.
q4   #    q5    1     left

q5   1    q5    1     left     // move left until you find Xs
q5   X    q2    X     left     // then repeat as above
```

Example: `111`

```
#111#######  =>  #111#######  =>  #111#######  =>  #111#######  =>
 ^q0               ^q1               ^q1               ^q1

#111#######  =>  #11X#######  =>  #11X1######  =>  #11X11#####  =>
   ^q2               ^q3               ^q4             ^q5

#11X11#####  =>  #11X11#####  =>  #1XX11#####  =>  #1XX11#####  =>
   ^q5             ^q2               ^q3               ^q3

#1XX11#####  =>  #1XX11#####  =>  #1XX111####  =>  #1XX1111###  =>
     ^q3               ^q3               ^q4             ^q5

#1XX1111###  =>  #1XX1111###  =>  #1XX1111###  =>  #1XX1111###  =>
     ^q5             ^q5             ^q5             ^q2

#1XX1111###  =>  #XXX1111###  =>  #XXX1111###  =>  #XXX1111###  =>
 ^q2               ^q3               ^q3               ^q3

#XXX1111###  =>  #XXX1111###  =>  #XXX1111###  =>  #XXX1111###  =>
     ^q3               ^q3               ^q3               ^q3

#XXX11111##  =>  #XXX111111#  =>  #XXX111111#  =>  #XXX111111#  =>
         ^q4             ^q5             ^q5             ^q5

#XXX111111#  =>  #XXX111111#  =>  #XXX111111#  =>  #XXX111111#  =>
     ^q5             ^q5             ^q5             ^q2

#XXX111111#  =>  #XXX111111#  =>  #XXX111111#
 ^q2             ^q2              ^hA
```